# Which Android database solutions are best for working with both online and offline-only users?

Tags: android, android-database

I plan to make a meditation journal app which stores all the user's data offline on the user's device, but also offers an option to sync this data to the cloud.

Firebase isn't really a good solution for this as it generally expects that the device will sync to the cloud as its primary source of data.

What is the best database solution which works 100% offline, but which can also be easily synced to the cloud to share the data across multiple devices? To narrow it down further, the cheapest option would also be preferred.

Comment: Opinion questions and sugestions for libraries and services are off topic

Comment: @GabeSechan it's a question with a specific answer. What solutions allow this (not many) and then narrow it down to one answer by being the cheapest.

Comment: No it isn't.  You're asking for opinions on libraries and programs.  That's off topic.  And I know of over a dozen packages that could answer this.  Any question that can be worded as "what software should I use" is pretty much always off topic here.

Comment: @GabeSechan you know over a dozen yet you haven't provided one. I'm glad this is how you spend your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sqlite [link](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) for offline and  SqlServer for online, when the user is offline use Sqlite and online SqlServer, just synchronize it when is online, but you need a good way to manage structured data in both sides or cases, see the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).

Answer (score 0):

use Room DB with kotlin coroutines, so you can call queries asyncronously.
and it is more easy to use

for more:
https://amitshekhar.me/blog/room-database-with-kotlin-coroutines